# How is it possible that documents are getting mapped but not getting reduced in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

In a mongoDB map reduce I have code that causes some documents to be mapped but not reduced.  I boiled it down to a very simple example

```
m = function(){
    var a = this.visit_last_action_time.getFullYear()
    var b = this.visit_last_action_time.getMonth()
    var c = this.visit_last_action_time.getDate()
    var key =  new Date(a,b,c)
    emit(key,{greeting:'hi'})
}


r = function(key,values){
    var sum = 0;
        for (index in values) {
            sum ++
        }
    return {count: sum}
}

    result = db.runCommand({
"mapreduce" : "piwik",
"map" : m,
"reduce" : r,
"out" : "temp2",
limit:500})
```

the result is

```
    {
        "result" : "temp2",
        "timeMillis" : 1461,
        "counts" : {
            "input" : 500,
            "emit" : 500,
            "reduce" : 13,
            "output" : 20
        },
        "ok" : 1
    }
> db.temp2.find({})
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-01-28T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-01-29T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "greeting" : "hi" } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-07-11T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "greeting" : "hi" } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-07-13T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "greeting" : "hi" } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-07-15T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-07-16T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 7 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-07-17T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 39 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-07-18T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 172 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-07-19T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 248 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-09-23T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-09-24T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 5 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-09-25T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 4 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-09-26T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-09-27T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-09-28T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 5 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-10-13T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "greeting" : "hi" } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-10-14T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "greeting" : "hi" } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-10-15T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "greeting" : "hi" } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-10-18T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "greeting" : "hi" } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2011-10-19T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 2 } }
```

As you can see from the "hi"s something strange is happening here.

How is it possible that documents are not getting reduced?

I am using mongo 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is it possible that documents are not getting reduced?

The Reduce will only be called when you need to reduce two or more values into a single value.

You can see this in the signature of the function. `reduce()` accepts an array of values and returns a single value.

The structure of `value` emitted from `map` should be the same as that returned by `reduce`.

In your case, your code is violating the following rule: `reduce(key, [a]) => a`.

You need to change two things:

```
m = ...
  emit(key,{count:1})
}

r = function(key,values){
    var sum = 0;
    for (index in values) {
        sum += values[index].count
    }
    return {count: sum}
}
```

Note how the structure of the emitted value is the same as the reduced value.